# Edit separate Date and time fields that are saved as one java.util.Date field

Tags: jsf

Entity:Meeting

```
private Date meetingDateAndTime;

@Transient 
String meetingDate;

@Transient
String hour;

@Transient
String minutes;
```

Bean:

```
saveMeeting(){
    String meetingTime = selectedMeeting.getHour()+":"+selectedMeeting.getMinutes();
    Date calculatedDate = getAppendedTimeForDate(selectedMeeting.meetingDate,meetingTime);
    selectedMeeting.setMeetingDateTime(calcualtedDate);
}

private static Date getAppendedTimeForDate(Date selectedDate,String t) throws Exception{
     String d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(selectedDate);
     String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
     Date calculatedDate=sdf.parse(d+" "+t);
     return calculatedDate;
}
```

AddEditMeeting.xhtml:

```
<h:inputText value="selectedMeeting.meetingDate"/>
<h:inputText value="selectedMeeting.hour"/>
<h:inputText value="selectedMeeting.minute"/>\
```

With separate inputText for `date`, `hour` and `minutes`, I am able to save the `meetingDateAndTime` correctly in the database in the `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm` format, but the requirement is to be able to edit these values as well i.e. when the user selects a meeting, an edit page opens with date, hour and minute fields already populated that the user can then edit and save back to the database.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You are combining date and time, parsing the combination to a `java.util.Date` and then saving it to the database. You need to separate them while retrieving a date from the database and display a date, hours and minutes separately in the associated input fields isolating by using some functions associated with the `java.util.Data` API. You could use some converters for this purpose. In addition to that, data/time is heavily dependent upon a specific time zone which you must consider adequately. The `java.util.Date` API is not what you want, when a time zone is to be taken into account.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. I understood that you'd like to preset the properties based on data from DB. But the answer to that is so obvious (just do the inverse of what you're doing right now, like `meetingDate = extractMeetingDateFrom(dateField)` or so), that I'm confused how exactly you're having a problem with that. Needless to say that this all is indeed a huge code smell.

Comment: Extracting and displaying on screen is not the issue. I am unable to edit the date once it has already been stored in the db.

Comment: I'm now yet more confused. You're **nowhere** telling how exactly you're "unable to edit" the data. You should be able to use the same form as you used to create the data. What step exactly fails? Editing the value in the input field? Pressing the submit button? Applying request values? Conversion/validation? Updating model values? Invoking the bean action method? Accessing updated values? Etc..etc.. I can at least tell that the `<h:inputText value>` syntax doesn't match ones shown in chapter 1 of a sane JSF book/tutorial, but I just assumed it to be a careless preparation of the question.

Comment: @PD "Any pointers are appreciated." <-- well, were my points not appreciated?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get rid of all the transient members, you do not need them.

Write code in the beginning of your page which takes the meetingDateAndTime,  breaks it down to date, hour, minute, and populates the form fields with it.

Then write additional code which gets invoked when the form is submitted, takes the values from the form fields, reconstructs the date, and stores it in meetingDateAndTime.

EDIT

Easily computable and rarely required data should be computed on demand, no storage should be occupied by them in memory. Also, whenever you have two data items which must always agree with each other, [Murphy's law (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) predicts that there will be a time when they will not agree.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my response